# Retrieving facebook friendlist and showing it in Tableview

Tags: iphone

I am using Facebook graph api to retrieve facebook's friend list.

I'm using this code:

```
-(IBAction)getMeFriendsButtonPressed:(id)sender  
{
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/friends" withGetVars:nil];
    NSLog(@"getMeFriendsButtonPressed: %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
}
```

And in return I am getting this at console.

```
getMeFriendsButtonPressed: 
{"data":[{"name":"name1","id":"504181912"},   
         {"name":"name2","id":"505621879"},
         {"name":"name3","id":"520845156"},
         {"name":"name4","id":"537539375"}
}
```

or something like this.

I want to get names, like name1, name2, name3 and show it in table view.

How can I create an array of these name?

Suggestion please
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The respone your are getting is JSON. You should use  JSON parser for parsing the JSON String

[JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)

Answer (score 4):

This is JSON output. You may refer to the JSON parsing tutorial at this link

http://www.xprogress.com/post-44-how-to-parse-json-files-on-iphone-in-objective-c-into-nsarray-and-nsdictionary/

Hope this works for you.